# Nestjs build takes forever after first build in AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, build, nestjs

I am doing a project using Nest.js and trying to deploy it to the AWS EC2 instance (t3.micro). However, there is a problem with build time.

When I freshly made the instance and build the code, it took under 10 seconds. However, after I changed my code at my local environment, pushed it to GitHub and pulled the code in the EC2 instance, suddenly the build started to take forever.

So I tried removing `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and also ran `yarn cache clean`, non of these worked. I have seen a few articles saying that the EC2 micro instance has small RAM, not very good CPU, so it might take a long time to build, but that doesn't explain the first build I ran right after making the instance.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Any solutions?

Following are the environment I am using.

```
AWS Instance: EC2 (t3.micro)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Node: 18.8.0
Nest.js: "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.11",
         "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.11"
```

Comment: May want to give a bit more information about howyou're actually building the Nest.js application. The problem could be there.

Comment: same happened with me i have to stop current serve like using pm2 stop id and then i make build and then run it